# Quartz simple trigger vs cron trigger

Tags: quartz-scheduler

For my enterprise application, i need do the batch operation with time of intervals. 
While referring quartz scheduler, there are two types. One is simple trigger and another one is cron trigger. 
I am confusing about these concepts. Please explain me with simple example.

Comment: @Srinivas answer gave you the details and documentation for CronTrigger. However, if you just want to run your batch "every X minutes/hours", use SimpleTrigger: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-05.html#lesson-5:-simpletrigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the examples given in the documentation.
[CronTrigger](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06.html)

> CronTrigger is often more useful than SimpleTrigger, if you need a job-firing schedule that recurs based on calendar-like notions, rather than on the exactly specified intervals of SimpleTrigger.

Some Examples
`“every Friday at noon” or “every weekday and 9:30 am”, or even “every 5 minutes between 9:00 am and 10:00 am on every Monday, Wednesday and Friday during January”`, .

> CronTrigger Example 1 - an expression to create a trigger that simply fires every 5 minutes
>
> “0 0/5 * * * ?”
>
> CronTrigger Example 2 - an expression to create a trigger that fires every 5 minutes, at 10 seconds after the minute (i.e. 10:00:10 am, 10:05:10 am, etc.).
>
> “10 0/5 * * * ?”
>
> CronTrigger Example 3 - an expression to create a trigger that fires at 10:30, 11:30, 12:30, and 13:30, on every Wednesday and Friday.
>
> “0 30 10-13 ? * WED,FRI”
>
> CronTrigger Example 4 - an expression to create a trigger that fires every half hour between the hours of 8 am and 10 am on the 5th and 20th of every month. Note that the trigger will NOT fire at 10:00 am, just at 8:00, 8:30, 9:00 and 9:30
>
> “0 0/30 8-9 5,20 * ?”